# Nodejs - Issues with socket connection webapp

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm currently have an issue creating a webapp. All of the pages that we are creating can be viewed through a function that gets the post data and displays it onto the page. The issue I'm having is that when loading the content, the corresponding JS for sockets does not execute.

I believe this is because we're using:

```
socket.on("connect")
```

and the connect event would only fire once, but I'm unsure about how to fix this.

An example of the JS I'm currently using can be seen below.

```
function runJs(){
    var url = document.location.pathname.toLowerCase();
    if(url == '/account/create'){
    var socket = io();

    //once the socket connects, make calls
    socket.on("connect", function(){=
        socket.on("accountCreated", function(data){
            if(typeof data.data.error !== "undefined"){
                jQuery("#error").text(data.data.error);
            }
            else{
                //account creation was successful and we're logged in.
                //redirect to the home page
                window.location.href = "/";
            }
        });
    });
}
```

When executing another function (not posted here, as it's not important), it updates the pages HTML and runs the runJs() function seen above. I have confirmed through console.log that the function is indeed being called, but the code within the socket.on does not execute unless the page is reloaded.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could fix this?

Comment: socket.on listens for events and socket.emit emits an event. Can you show your server side code to see hoe events are handled?

Comment: are you emitting the `accountCreated` on serverside. Besides there is no need of using `socket.on("connect",__)` here, you can directly use `socket.on("accountCreated", __)`. But why are you not passing url in `io()`

Comment: @HimaniAgrawal - The server side code for this does not matter, as that executes properly. The problem is with the socket.on on the front end, but I don't know what to replace it with. This code sample also should have had an emit, but the issue still remains.

Comment: @Nivesh - io() does not require URL to be passed to work properly. As for the need to have connect, that is true in the code I copied. It should have had an emit, which requires a socket to exist.